# php-fpm: shell_exec not working to execute some scripts

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian

> server: Debian 11, nginx, php8.1-fpm

i want to execute this command from php but is not working, when i run from terminal (root)it works

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/dos2unix /var/www/script.sh');
echo $output;
```

when i run the code below it works

```
$output = shell_exec('ls /usr/bin/');
echo $output;
```

i think the user that run the script is **www-data** based on the code below

```
 $linuxUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid());
 echo $linuxUser['name'];
result is www-data
```

also i added this in  **visudo** just to test but still not working

> www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Whoa, the last bit is interesting! Could you give me the address of that system? I'd like to use that mile wide open security hole you created! ;-) Seriously: do not grant the http server process the permission to perform _any_ command, even highly privileged ones, on your system!

Comment: What happens if you make yourself the http server user and execute said call? And what does your http server's error log file and the log file the fpm server writes contain?

Comment: May I know what you are trying to achieve here `$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/dos2unix /var/www/script.sh');` by running the script.sh

Comment: /usr/bin/dos2unix  is just an example. coz lost of script doesnt work , and some works

Answer (score 0):

in **visudo**
when u paste this

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

make sure it is at the very bottom line or it will not work, so move that line at the end of the file